# can't align text vertically - angularJS + bootstrap + flexbox

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I've lost so much time trying to figure out why I can't align the text inside these cells vertically? I tried everything :

```
align-items: center;
vertical-align: middle;
justify-content: center;
justify-items: center;
```

none of these seems to be working, I tried putting them in the cointainers, in the cells themselves, but nothing..then I have a complete different table, always with flex, and there it works, so I'm lost,

here the fiddle, I'm trying to vertically align the cells with some text in them, anyone with a working solution? what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/buwgq14a/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` by adding some `css` in your existing syle  and you are done

```
    .epYearlyHeaderCell,
.epYearlyHeaderCell2,
.epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:first-child, .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(3), .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(5), .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(7), .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(8), .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(10), .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:last-child, .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(2), .epYearlyHeaderMonthCell:nth-child(4){
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/buwgq14a/21/)

Comment: tried this solution so many times but I was always missing : display: flex;, what a rookie mistake! thank you

Comment: i've minified the code for you, simply put that code in your css and you are done with what you wanted :)

Answer (score 4):

Replace the `span` with `div`

like

```
<div class="epYearlyHeaderCell">
   <div class="epYearlyHeaderCellText">222</div>
</div>


.epYearlyHeaderCell{
   display:table;
}


.epYearlyHeaderCellText
{
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the span

```
.epYearlyHeaderCell span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing this in your code :

```
.epYearlyHeaderCell,
.epYearlyHeaderMonthCell {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[Updated JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lus0yq1u/1/)

Comment: thank you as well for you solution! had to give the solution to the other user who posted a couple of minutes before, thank you anyway! I was missing: display:flex, in the cells!